# Positive and negative matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, positive-definite

Lemma: Let $A=(a_{ij})$ and $B=(b_{ij})$ be two positive semi-definite matrices, i.e.
$$\sum_{i,j=1}^{n} a_{ij} x_{i}x_{j} \geq 0$$ for all $x=(x_1,...,x_n) \in R^n$, similarly for B. 
Then
$$\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}a_{ij}b_{ij} \geq 0$$.

Based on above lemma I want to show that: if $A=(a_{ij})$ is a symmetric positive matrix ($A \geq 0$) and $B=(b_{ij})$ is non-positive symetric matrix ($B \leq 0$) then $$\sum_{i,j=1}^{n}a_{ij}b_{ij} \leq 0$$.

Thank you very much for help.

Comment: $(-B)$ is positive definite. Can you finish from here?

Comment: Yes, using lemma for A and -B gives $-\sum a_{ij} b_{ij} \geq 0$ thus $\sum a_{ij} b_{ij} \leq 0$. Thanks a lot, i dont know why I didn't solve this in that way :D